# how to call a method using percentage

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am having two methods like method1 and method2.I am getting a percentage(like 30%) from server.If it is returning 30% means ,i should call method1 30% only.How to do this?shall I use any arc4random() function?

Comment: I don´t understand very well,what you want, but maybe using this help you:    [self performSelector:@selector(thisCouldBeANSStringVariable)];

Comment: Can i see the returning value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// I assume that it will give value between 0..100
float percentage = getPercentageFromServer();

if (percentage > 0.0f && (arc4random() % 101) <= percentage) {
    [self method1];
} else {
    [self method2];
}
```

`(arc4random() % 101)` will give us number from 0 to 100,
so if it's less or equal to percentage we will call method1, otherwise method2.
This means if server will response 30, then with 30% chance method 1 will be called, and with 70% chance method2.

Comment: It's possible that `(arc4random() % 101)` will be `0` **and** `percentage` will be `0` and `method1` will still be called.  A `0%` chance means it should never be called.

Comment: Using your original code: `if (percentage > 0.0f && (arc4random() % 101) <= percentage) {`